# population category dropdown and sub category onselect

Tags: php, html

I want to display categories and if the category is selected then display parent's sub categories... I know there is some thread about this question but none of them fit to my problem.

I did 2 functions:

---- one for get all categories ----

```
    function get_cats() {
    
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => '-1',
                'post_type' => 'cust_categories',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => false
            );
    
            $cust_query = get_posts($args);
    
            if (!empty($cust_query)) {
                $counter = 0;
                foreach ($cust_query as $key => $dir) {
                    $selected = '';
                    if (intval($dir->ID) === intval($current)) {
                        $selected = 'selected';
                    }
    
                     echo '<option ' . $selected . ' value="' . $dir->ID . '">' . get_the_title($dir->ID) . '</option>';
                }
            }
    
    
}
```

---- one for get all sub categories ---

```
function get_subcat($category) {
    $parent_category_ID = $category->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'hierarchical' => 1,
        'show_option_none' => '',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => $parent_category_ID,
        'taxonomy' => 'sub_category'
    );
    $subcategories = get_categories($args);
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
        $link = get_term_link( $subcategory->slug, $subcategory->taxonomy );
        echo '<option value="'.$link.'">'.$subcategory->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

And I did a form which displays them in a dropdown:

```
<div class="form">
<label for="category" class="formlabel">Category</label>
<div class="fieldcontainer">
<select name="category" id="category">
<?php echo get_cats(); ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
                            
<div class="form">
<label for="sub_category" class="formlabel">Sub Category</label>
<div class="fieldcontainer">
<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php echo get_subcat(); ?>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Everything works fine but I want to display the selected category's (parent's) sub category only in the sub category dropdown, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll want to populate the subcategory dropdown using AJAX after the parent category has been selected.  So your `get_subcat()` function should work fine but instead of echoing it, call it with AJAX and return the results so instead of loading it immediately, you'd get it to run via AJAX when the parent category dropdown changes using `.on( 'change' )`.  Then you'd `.append()` the returned results to the `#sub_category` select.

Comment: Yes, I knew that I need the onchange ajax event and append but I can't figure out how I can replace the echoing with the ajax functions. Never did anything with ajax